# how to insert an item to an array that is inside an object in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following user model,

```js
{
  teams: {
    owner: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Team'
    }],
    member: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Team'
    }]
  }
}
```

when user creates a team, I have to update the above user collection by adding the _id of the created team to the 'owner' array.I tried to use $push and $addToset but as the team is an object I couldn't do it.Could any one suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.update({_id: _id}, {$push: { 'teams.member': ObjectId }})
```

Comment: Thank you very much,sorry for being dense ,I have a question will the same will work while quering the database like {'team.member':{$ne:teamId}}